# change x-axis values in plt.plot()

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have the following plot:
[time characteristic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2Ru0.png)

Code is following:

```
pointdat=tracesM[458,20*250:(50)*250]
plt.plot(pointdat)
plt.show()
```

Where pointdat contains 7500 values (time samples) for a particular point (458 in my case). 7500 is for 30 seconds. So each second should have 250 values. I'd love to see my x-axis in seconds (from 0 till 30) and scaled in needed way.

Tried:

```
pointdat=tracesM[458,20*250:(50)*250]
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 7501, 250)/250)
plt.plot(pointdat)
plt.show()
```

The result was:
[xticks was added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMIKy.png)

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `xticks` function of `matplotlib.pyplot`.

```
pointdat=tracesM[458,20*250:(50)*250]
plt.plot(pointdat)

plt.xticks(np.arange(0, 7501, 250)/250)

plt.show()
```

Comment: I've edited my question higher to show the result. Unfortunately it doesn't work how i'd like to expect.

Comment: I tried the same, it works though. I generated it using `numpy` to match your values, can you provide your data? https://imgur.com/a/2bEJW7C

Comment: which version of `matplotlib`, you are using.

Comment: Version is '3.1.1' .

Comment: Can you give the data, I used `np.random.random((7500))`. Either you use this code to generate and then, plot. Did you see the image, there it works like you want, right?

Comment: To provide data is complicated beacause it's just a little part of data that i've preprocessed. I can say that 'tracesM' is type int32 of size (480,15000) and pointdat is type int32 of size (7500, ) if it could help.

Comment: `plt.gcf().set_size_inches(20, 20)`. This line should be used before you are plotting. Try this then plot. Let's see.

Comment: I've used this function instead of xticks (not sure that it should be at this place) but it just changed the width and hight of axises. But the result was like at first image in my question,